# SQL: 'transpose' a number of bit/binary columns into one multivariate column

Tags: sql, binary, multiple-columns, bit

Say I have the following data:

```
name  is_married  has_dog  wants_children
Tom            1        1               1
Dick           0        1               1
Harry          0        0               0
```

But I want to yield the following data:

```
name  description
Tom   is_married
Tom   has_dog
Tom   wants_children
Dick  has_dog
Dick  wants_children
```

i.e., I want to place the information held in those various binary fields into a form where each 'binary positive' is shown in its own row.

Is there a way of making this scalable, if there are hundreds of binary columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a routine that should scale.

- Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA system table to find the column names
- Use a cursor to loop
  through the column names
- Looping through, create prepare/execute to
  execute a specific query finding the users with that attribute AND
  turning the attribute (column name) into a "description" field
- Store
  those values in a temp table for name/description
- Select the results.

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN  
  DECLARE sql_stmt varchar(200);
  DECLARE exit_loop INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('select name, "', column_name, '" As Description from tbl where ' , column_name, '=1')
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl'
  and column_name <> 'Name'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (name varchar(200), description varchar(200));

OPEN col_names;

the_loop: LOOP

   FETCH col_names 
   INTO sql_stmt; 

   IF exit_loop THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        LEAVE the_loop;
   END IF;

SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp(name, description) ',sql_stmt);


PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;

END LOOP the_loop;

SELECT * from temp ORDER BY name;

DROP TABLE temp;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And the results:

```
mysql> call myproc();
+------+----------------+
| name | description    |
+------+----------------+
| Tom  | ismarried      |
| Tom  | hasdog         |
| Tom  | wants_children |
| Dick | hasdog         |
| Dick | wants_children |
+------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```